# how to update if exist else insert in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my database if ID is already exist else insert if ID is not exist.

**process.php:**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "maindata";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
 die("<center>Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</center");
}     

$id = $_POST['id'];   
$aname = $_POST['aname'];   
$xsummary = $_POST['xsummary'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE ID = $id");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == $id) 
{
 $sql="update info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary='$xsummary'";
} 
else {
 $sql="insert into AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary= '$xsummary'";
}
```

Some one help me on my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use the INSERT IGNORE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... i'm only new in php and still watching a tutorial

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection attack!  https://xkcd.com/327/  Never use input supplied by the user to build an SQL query string.  You should use prepared statements instead.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what should i do to improve my code and ignore the SQL injection attack

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on below code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "maindata";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("<center>Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</center");
}     

$id = $_POST['id'];   
$aname = $_POST['aname'];   
$xsummary = $_POST['xsummary'];

$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM info WHERE ID = $id");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
{
    $sqlUpdate="update info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary= '$xsummary'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlUpdate);
} else {
    $sqlInsert="insert into info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary= '$xsummary'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlInsert);
}
```

Your actual issue in code, you were connection database with mysqli, but fetching data from table with mysql. Please use this code and will work fine.

*Note :- There was an error in insert statement, Please update and this will work.

Comment: thanks man the update is working but if the id is not exist on the database the sqlInssert is not working... thumbs up to you

Comment: Hello Jonel, There was an error in insert statement, Please update, this will work.

Comment: Sir still not working the insert i also added the "set" before AccountName.... i think the table name is missing in $sqlInsert... but i already added the table name and still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "maindata";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("<center>Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " </center");
}     
$id = isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] ? $_POST['id'] : 0;   
$aname = $_POST['aname'];   
$xsummary = $_POST['xsummary'];

$stmt=mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT into info (`ID`, `AccountName`, `ExecutiveSummary`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `AccountName`=VALUES(`AccountName`),
    `ExecutiveSummary`=VALUES(`ExecutiveSummary`)
");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iss', $id, $aname, $xsummary);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I added parameter binding here for you to learn. Don't insert information coming from your inputs directly to the query. Its unsafe.

Comment: have an error Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\wamp64 in mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iss', $aname, $xsummary); and mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

Comment: updated code... added $id on the bind... with that warning, you need to troubleshoot your mysql connection...

Comment: still have an error, --Error Inserting into the database.: 
Query was empty--

Answer (score 0):

All is good need to replace
**this**

```
    if (mysql_num_rows() == $id) 
    {
     $sql="update info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary='$xsummary'";
    }
```

**with**

```
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows()>0) 
{
 $sql="update info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary='$xsummary' where ID= $id";
}
```

Comment: have an error of Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\wamp64

Comment: Updated answer will solve the issue. @joneltimblaco

Comment: still have an 3 error Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C in $sql=mysqli_query and Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C in mysqli_query($sql); and Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C in if (mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
$sql        = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE ID = $id");
$num_rows   = @mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    //update query
    $sql="update info set AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary='$xsummary'";
} else {
    //insert query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO info ('AccountName', 'ExecutiveSummary')
    VALUES ('$aname', '$xsummary')";
}
```

Comment: Error Inserting into the database.: INSERT INTO info ---- have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: Is ID is primary key or any thing else?

Comment: $sql="insert into info AccountName= '$aname', ExecutiveSummary= '$xsummary'";

Comment: Table name is missing

Comment: table name is info

Comment: Yes I know. But u miss it insert query. check your insert query.

Comment: Use this query.  $sql = "INSERT INTO info ('AccountName', 'ExecutiveSummary')
    VALUES ('$aname', '$xsummary')";

Comment: sir still same error as i said on my first comment. Error Inserting into the database.: INSERT INTO info ---- have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Answer (score -1):

Try to something like this

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "maindata";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
     die("<center>Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</center");
    }     

    $id = $_POST['id'];   
    $aname = $_POST['aname'];   
    $xsummary = $_POST['xsummary'];

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE ID = $id");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count > 0) 
    {
      $sql="update info set AccountName= '$aname',  ExecutiveSummary='$xsummary' where ID =".$id;
    } 
    else {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO info ('AccountName', 'ExecutiveSummary')
VALUES ('$aname', '$xsummary')";

    }
```

Comment: have an error of Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\wamp64

Comment: I have update my anwser Please check again

Comment: still have an 3 error Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp64 in $sql=mysqli_query and Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C in $result and Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C in $count